# What is the mapping of index to day of the week with using Fast AI's datepart function?

Tags: fast-ai

What is the mapping of index to day of the week with using Fast AI's datepart function? It's not explained in the docs.

Code:

```
add_datepart(df, date_column)
```

https://docs.fast.ai/tabular.transform.html#add_datepart